# How to number increment with limit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using number field with plus and minus for product quantity select for a project. I need to set a max limit when I press plus icon. I am using below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1 );
        $input.change();
       
        return false;
    });
});
```

How to set a maximum limit for when i press + icon.

Comment: You're doing `$input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1 );`. Just split that up and you can easily add a range check. You are already doing this in the .minus part...

Comment: yes @ChrisG. Thank you for advise.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/87Ltocgv/

Comment: if greater than max.... set it to the max..... Basic logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you'd limit it to 99 for example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
         var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) + 1;
        count = count > 99 ? 99 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You trigger DOM Manipulation function even if not needed.

Comment: I like this code, the functions for minus and plus are almost same with little changes and I am using this code in my project.  Thank you very much.

Comment: See here for a better way (DRY principle): https://jsfiddle.net/87Ltocgv/

Comment: This code is indeed not ideal, but I didn't feel like what OP wanted was a class on DRY principles, the change is so easy i think he's really struggling to write JS. I tried to give the most beginner-friendly answer.

Answer (score 1):

Optimize for readability by using `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`

```
const MINIMUM = 1
const MAXIMUM = 99

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.minus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var newCount = Math.max(parseInt($input.val()) - 1, MINIMUM);
            $input.val(newCount);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.plus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var newCount = Math.min(parseInt($input.val()) + 1, MAXIMUM)
            $input.val(newCount);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: See here for a better way (DRY principle): https://jsfiddle.net/87Ltocgv/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the current value. If the value exceeds the limit, ignore the action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.minus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.plus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');

            if ($input.val() > 100) {
                return;
            }

            $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1 );
            $input.change();
           
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: It is working perfect now. Thank you very much..

Comment: See here for a better way (DRY principle): https://jsfiddle.net/87Ltocgv/

Answer (score 0):

The static function Math.min() returns the lowest-valued number passed into it, or NaN if any parameter isn't a number and can't be converted into one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.minus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.plus').click(function () {
            var max = 100;
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            $input.val(Math.min(max, parseInt($input.val()) + 1 ));
            $input.change();
           
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: You trigger DOM Manipulation function even if not needed.

Comment: See here for a better way (DRY principle): https://jsfiddle.net/87Ltocgv/